# Is there a salutation/greeting recognizing the last day of Channukah for my Jewish friends?

Tags: chanuka, social-convention

Is there a salutation/greeting recognizing the last day of Channukah for my Jewish friends?

At the beginning of this holiday, I wish them well. Is there a similar phrase that I should use as this holiday ends that is a sign of respect for them and their beliefs? (that I as a non-Jewish person can/should say)

Comment: would "Happy last day of Channukah" not suffice? The 8 days are all parts of a singular holiday. Happy Channukah is as valid on day 8 as on day 1 (or 4).

Comment: Gmar chasima tova, among chasidim. (supposedly some people also say "a freilekhn zos chanukah"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your efforts to show respect for your Jewish friends.

I'm not aware of any special greeting for the last day of Chanuka, in particular. "Happy Chanuka" is the greeting commonly used in English, and that's perfectly appropriate for each day of the holiday. There's no problem with a non-Jewish person using this greeting; I'm sure it will be accepted in the spirit in which it's offered.